# Setting up a wall with a slit inside the domain of a 2D wave being solved using the fourier-spectral method

Tags: waves, computational-physics, fourier-transform, simulations, differential-equations

The wave equation is given by:

$$ \frac{\partial^2 u}{\partial t^2} = \alpha^2 \cdot \left( \frac{\partial^2 u}{\partial x^2} + \frac{\partial^2 u}{\partial y^2} \right)$$

If we assume the solution to be in the form of:

$$ u(x,y,t) = \sum_{n=0}^{\infty} \sum_{m=0}^{\infty} U_{mn}(t) \cdot \sin(\frac{m \pi}{L} x) \cdot \sin(\frac{n\pi}{L} y) $$

We can get the following system of ODEs for the fourier coefficients:

$$ \frac{d^2 U_{mn}}{d t^2} = -\alpha^2 \cdot \left( \frac{m^2 \pi^2}{L^2} + \frac{n^2 \pi^2}{L^2} \right) \cdot U_{mn} $$

With this I can get an expression for the coefficient at a future time, given its current value:

$$ U_{mn}(t+\Delta t) = U_{mn}(t)\cdot e^{-i\omega \Delta t}  $$

I ensured dirilecht boundary condiditons by setting the fourier coefficients to be zero at the edges of my domain.

```
newCoefficients = currentCoefficients * np.exp(-1j * self.angularFreqs * timeStep)
newCoefficients[0, :] = 0
newCoefficients[-1, :] = 0
newCoefficients[:, 0] = 0
newCoefficients[:, -1] = 0
```

I've tried out the code and it seems to work at first glance. An example with a standing wave is given below - I had to reduce the resolution of the domain to be able to upload it.

[image: Standing wave sim]

Would it be possible to simulate a vertical wall with a slit inside the domain? I know that the fourier basis functions have special domain requirements so I'm not entirely sure whether it's even possible. If it's possible how can I implement it? I've tried setting the fourier coefficients to be zero at the points where the wall exists but it doesn't give me the desired effect.

I'm talking about a wall like the one given below.

[image]

Here's a [link to the code](https://github.com/thenu-k/WaveSimulator/blob/main/Logic/Spectral.py) if necessary.

Comment: Seems to me that FEM or FDM would be better suited for this problem than applying the Fourier method.